# Full URL does not match in Ubuntu Linux server compare to Xampp Windows local server

Tags: php, linux, laravel-5.3

I have this URL in Ubuntu Linux Server:

```
http://mywebsite.xxx/getapp/1?ref=134&reseller=my_name&campaign=school_holiday
```

If I used in my xampp localhost (Windows 10) like:

```
http://localhost:8000/getapp/1?ref=134&reseller=my_name&campaign=school_holiday
```

Then everything able to keep track with all query strings captured. But in the Ubuntu Linux server with the same codes none of all the query strings were captured.

How to let the URL able to keep track in server same as in local?What should I do?

Thanks.

---

Sample codes I've tried.

```
public function MyLogLib(Request $request)
{
    $data_insert = new LogLib();
    $data_insert->ref      =  $request->input('ref');
    $data_insert->reseller =  $request->input('reseller');
    $data_insert->campaign =  $request->input('campaign');
    $data_insert->save();
}
```

---

Rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Also share your code where you capture these paramo?

Comment: You are not getting 404 but just that you can't get the url parameters. Am I right?

Comment: @Rishi see my updated question.

Comment: Exactly @SaravananSampathkumar

Comment: It's look like `$request` does not give full information. If I use `$_REQUEST` then the data can be capture finely.

Comment: Thats strange. Normal $request should work.

Comment: There is no problem with the `.htacces` I think just only `$request`.

Comment: Are both environments using Apache? What are your rewrite rules in each system? It looks to me like you've left off the `[QSA]` flag in the Linux environment

Comment: Yes Apache @Phil.

Comment: @Phil I do not understand what do you mean with `[QSA]` flag. (^_^)

Comment: I got it @Phil. https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA

Comment: It's an Apache `RewriteRule` flag. You're yet to answer my question *"What are your rewrite rules in each system?"*

Comment: @Phil see my updated question.

Comment: Simple fix, change `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]`

Comment: @Phil still not working....